# Rails, given an array of items, how to delete in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following:

```
@users = User.where(:state => 1)

which 15 for: @users.length
```

In the rails console, is there a way to then delete all those records, perhaps by doing something like `@users.delete`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model class has [a `delete` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete) (and a [`destroy` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy)) that can take a single ID or a an Array of IDs to delete (or destroy). Passing an array will issue only a *single* `DELETE` statement, and is the best option in this case.

```
User.delete @users.map { |u| u.id }
# or
User.destroy @users.map { |u| u.id }
```

Note that when you call `destroy` on an ActiveRecord model, it creates an instance of the record before deleting it (so callbacks, etc. are run). In this case, since you already have fully instantiated objects, if you really do want to call `destroy` (instead of `delete`), it is probably more performant to use the method in [J-_-L's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761377/rails-given-an-array-of-items-how-to-delete-in-the-console/5761402#5761402) and iterate over them yourself.

Comment: I've always done it using the each block like in J-_-L's answer, but it also looks like (in Rails 3 at least), that you can do `User.destroy @users` as well.

Comment: you don't need to do overtime job. Just call. @users.destroy_all

Answer (score 14):

```
@users = User.where(:state => 1)
```

The simplest way is to use `destroy_all` or `delete_all`:

```
@users.destroy_all
# OR
@users.delete_all
```

**That's all**

Answer (score 2):

yep:

```
@users.each{ |u| u.destroy }
```

Comment: Be aware this is horribly inefficient. You call a new SQL query for each user that gets deleted, which can stack fast.

Answer (score 2):

`@users.destroy_all` is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

the destroy_all or delete_all will execute a query like this: `DELETE FROM USERS`, so it will remove all the records in the table!! not only the records of the objects in the array!
So I think the best way is `User.delete @users.map { |u| u.id }`

Answer (score 0):

Destroy all is the simplest way.  Here is the syntax:

```
User.destroy_all(id: [2, 3])
```

Comment: destroy_all do not take any argument, this won't work, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688915/147079

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need this. In Rails 6, if you already know what you want to delete and you want to do it in an efficient way on many records, you can use either:

```
Model.delete_by(id: array_of_id, other_condition: value)
```

Which is based on `delete_all`, documentation:

- `delete_by`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_by
- `delete_all`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all

or:

```
Model.destroy_by(id: array_of_id, other_condition: value)
```

Which is based on `destroy_all`, documentation:

- `destroy_by`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_by
- `destroy_all`:
  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all

The difference is that `delete_by` will not run callbacks, validations nor will it delete dependent associations. While `destroy_by` will do all of that (but in a slower way). So it really depends on what you want to achieve for your application.

Both of those methods should be prefered over .where.something because they will create a single SQL query, not multiple of them.